# How to place textview near to Right side of logo android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, android-layout-weight

I have logo (id is tri_logo) which is placed at right side. Near to that,  to left of that I need to place version count (id is version_text). But version count is not displaying near to the tri_logo which is right.

In simple, I need to place like this.You can see v1.0 is placed near to the right side of tri_logo.

```
          <Centered Icon which is already placed>                        v1.0 <tri_logo>
```

Below is xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lout_profile_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/top_view_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTopProfile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/hdr_img_padding"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTopProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hdr_name_padding" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/version_text" //this is not fitting near to below logo
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="v1.7"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tri_logo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/tri_logo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u share your expected output with question

Comment: 1.0 <logo> both should come towards right. I don't want to disturb other things. Near to the logo which is right, I need to place version_text

Comment: can share anys image  of your required output  @walter

Comment: i need to place here. I have marked a green square. There number should be placed. https://pasteboard.co/HkF66cF.png @NileshRathod

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lout_profile_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/top_view_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTopProfile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/hdr_img_padding"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTopProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hdr_name_padding" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="v1.7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tri_logo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/tri_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need to remove the weight?

Comment: no.. Not fitting properly. Icon looks too big and centered icon and text gets moved.  this is my requirement https://pasteboard.co/HkF66cF.png

Comment: what's your icon size?

Comment: 81*88 is the size of the tri_logo